# Type definition for a function returning extended anonymous class

Tags: typescript

I am trying to create a function which takes a class as parameter (not class instance but class itself) and returns another class which extends the class given in parameter.

I tried to define typescript function as follows and I get the following error: `Type 'typeof (Anonymous class)' is not assignable to type 'T'`

```
function extendClass<T>(base: T): T  {
    return class extends base{
    };
}
```

My example usage of the function above:

```
class A {
}

const B = extendClass(A); // B is an extended class of A

let b = new B(); // b is instance of class B
```

What is the correct type definition of the extendClass function??

Answer (score 3):

You need to make sure the argument passed to `extendClass` is a class, not an instance. On the type level, a class can be represented as a *newable function*:

```
new (...args: any[]) => any
```

To make it more readable, let's give it an alias.

```
interface Constructable {
    new (...args: any[]): any;
}
```

Now we have everything we need!

```
function extendClass<T extends Constructable>(Base: T) {
    return class extends Base {};
};
```

The return type, however, it's a bit messy to write by hand, because it needs to address both the type of returned class and the prototype chain. We can use type inference to do the work for us:

```
function extendClass<T extends Constructable>(BaseClass: T): typeof DerivedClass {
    const DerivedClass = class extends BaseClass {};

    return DerivedClass;
}
```

The derived class is assigned to a local variable just so we can read and use its inferred type.

Comment: what about function return type ?

Comment: @laltin Just let the compiler infer it :) If no members are added you can use `T`.  Do you really really really want to specify the return type if you have extra members ? I can provide it but it's really ugly and there is really no reason to write it out.

Comment: Yes, an explicit definition would look ugly. There is another option:


function extendClass<T extends Constructable>(BaseClass: T): typeof DerivedClass {
    const DerivedClass = class extends BaseClass {};

    return DerivedClass;
};

Comment: @TitianCernicova-Dragomir if I would let compiler infer it then there is no need for using template. yeah but thank you for response. For my case there are no new methods so just using T would work I think.

Comment: @KarolMajewski Thank you! I didn't know that I can use typeof a parameter inside function as return type, that solves the whole problem.

Comment: Is it possible to do the same thing to signify "implementability"? I know interfaces aren't runtime objects but just for type safety and for something like

`const ImplementingClass = class implements BaseInterface {};`

Comment: This implementation is giving me an error:

`Return type of exported function has or is using private name 'DerivedClass'.(4060)`

maybe this wasn't an issue then the question was originally posted

Answer (score 2):

You need to specify that `T` is a constructor to be able to use it as a base class for the annonymous class in the function. With regard to the return type my recommendation is to let the compiler infer this one. T

If the anonymous class adds no members that you want to access from outside the function you can just use `T` as the return type, but if you add members just let the compiler infer.

```
function extendClass<T extends new (...a: any[])=> any>(base: T)  {
    return class extends base{
    };
}
class A {
}

const B = extendClass(A); // B is an extended class of A
type B = InstanceType<typeof B>

let b:B = new B(); // b is instance of class B
```

If you add no public members you can just use `T` as the return type:

```
export function extendClass<T extends new (...a: any[]) => any>(base: T): T {
    return class extends base {
    }
}
```

If you leave the inferred version and generate the declarations, you can actually see how the return type would be declared explicitly if we add memebers to `T`:

```
export function extendClass<T extends new (...a: any[]) => any>(base: T): {
    new (...a: any[]): {
        test(): void;
    };
} & T {
    return class extends base {
        test() { }
    }
}
```

You can use this type in your code and it should work as expected.

Comment: @laltin added a version with explicit return type annotations.